# Unexplainable percentage error calculating French Roulette estimations

Tags: r, probability, percentage

I am working on a project for class: It's about the statistical evaluation of four different French Roulette (37 numbers) strategies. 
The first two are very simple:

- A. Betting on Red one Time
- B. Betting on a Number one Time

Please find the code below:

```
BettingOnRed <- function(){
  ball <- sample(1:37, 1, replace=TRUE)  
  if(ball <= 18)  amount_won <- 1
  else            amount_won <- -1
  c(amount_won, 1)
}

BettingOnNumber <- function() {
  myNumber <- 17
  ball <- sample(0:36, 1, replace=TRUE)
  if(myNumber == ball)  amount_won <- 35
  else                  amount_won <- -1
  c(amount_won, 1)
}
```

Each function returns a vector of `length = 2` containing the amount won and the number of bets made (which is always equal to one in these two functions: this value plays a role in the other strategies...).

Even though they appear to be simple, if we calculate the percentage error of the expected winnings and the proportion of wins per game, we partly get huge errors. Please see the table below:

[image: Click to see the table]

In order to calculate the expected values, I set up a function `simulation()` which repeats each game 100,000 times and calculates the values you find in the table.

What I don't understand is: Why is the percentage error of the winnings per game B so huge, whereas the percentage error of the proportion of games won of B is so small ?

Please find here the formulas we used to calculate the exact values and the percentage error for game B:

- Let `EstWin` be the estimation of winnings per game B.
- Let `EstProp` be the estimation of the proportion of games B won.

The respective exact values are:

- ExactWin = 1/37*35 - 36/37 = -1/37
- ExactProp = 1/37

Percentage Errors:

- PercErrorWin = (EstWin - ExactWin)/ExactWin
- PercErrorProp = (EstProp - ExactProp)/ExactProp

How do you explain this error? Why are the errors of B not the same? Am I missing an important fact about probability here ?

Find below the responsible part of my function 'simulation':
(As first argument, it takes one of the two functions from above)

```
simulation <- function(f, n = 100000){
  result <- numeric(8)
  winnings <- numeric(n)
  games_won <- numeric(n)
  for (i in 1:n){
    fnct <- f()
    winnings[i]  <- fnct[1]
    games_won[i] <- ifelse(fnct[1] > 0, 1, 0)
  }
  result[1] <- mean(winnings)
  result[2] <- mean(games_won)
  result
}
```

Note that this is not the whole function, I just deleted the unnecessary part for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** your results seem correct; there's more variation than you think (variation in bet-on-number is *much* greater than variation in bet-on-red ...)

There are lots of aspects of your simulations that could be streamlined, but I think your basic framework is correct.  Really the only thing that you're missing is the amount of variation expected in the output; if you examine this you'll see that the deviations between observed and expected are really not surprising. (You could actually compute this variance analytically, but here I'll do it by brute force.)

Simulate 100 runs, each with 100,000 games. I'm using `plyr::raply()` for convenience (it assembles your results automatically and implements a progress bar), but you could do it just as well with `replicate()`, or with a `for` loop.

```
set.seed(101)
library(plyr)
rr <- raply(100,simulation(BettingOnNumber,100000),.progress="text")
```

Plot the distribution of mean winnings: blue=expected, red=observed from your single simulation.

```
par(las=1,bty="l")
hist(rr[,1],col="gray",breaks=30,
     xlab="mean amount won in 100,000 games",
     ylab="Frequency (100 runs)")
exp_val <- -0.02703
obs_val <- -0.04852
abline(v=c(obs_val,exp_val),col=c("red","blue"),lwd=2)
```

[image]

Here's a computation of how surprising this degree of deviation is:

```
mean(abs(rr[,1]-exp_val)>abs(obs_val-exp_val)) ## 0.21
```

This means that you'd get the degree of deviation between expected and observed that you saw, or more deviation, about 21% of the time (this is essentially a frequentist p-value for your result).

Try this experiment with the betting-on-red strategy and you'll see how much smaller the variance is ...

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation !